# Props turns out to be undefined in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-state

Hi I was trying to setState for my app based on the values of Props I was relying on values of prop for my state , But when I passed the function to setState the props I received were undefined , don't know why , I followed [this document](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) for reference. You can read the section that says **State Updates May Be Asynchronous**
Below is my code (code snippet from File Form.js)

```
this.props.setTodos(function (_, props) {
      console.log("this is props:" + props);
      return [
        ...props.todos,
        { text: props.inputText, completed: false, id: Math.random() *            1000 },
      ];
    });
```

Code for App.js File where I pass props

```
import "./App.css";
import Form from "./components/Form";
import TodoList from "./components/TodoList";
import React, { useState } from "react";
function App() {
  const [inputText, setText] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <h1>My Todolist </h1>
      </header>
      <Form
        todos={todos}
        setTodos={setTodos}
        setText={setText}
        inputText={inputText}
      />
      <TodoList />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Full code for Form.js file

```
import React from "react";

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  handler = (e) => {
    // console.log(e.target.value);
    this.props.setText(e.target.value);
  };
  submitTodoHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.props.setTodos(function (_, props) {
      console.log("this is props:" + props);
      return [
        ...props.todos,
        { text: props.inputText, completed: false, id: Math.random() * 1000 },
      ];
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <input onChange={this.handler} type="text" className="todo-input" />
          <button
            onClick={this.submitTodoHandler}
            className="todo-button"
            type="submit"
          >
            <i className="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
          </button>
          <div className="select">
            <select name="todos" className="filter-todo">
              <option value="all">All</option>
              <option value="completed">Completed</option>
              <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Form;
```

I don't know why my props are undefined ? Thanks

Comment: you need to remove `props` parameter from your `this.props.setTodos` function, as it accepts only prevState parameter

Comment: if I remove the parameter how could I access the props , please elaborate little @alexnik42 ,  the docs says it accepts props too

Comment: You have already passed props in your constructor, so you can access them directly in props.setTodos function.

Comment: Yes but the docs says that's not a good practice because sometimes it may cause bugs as the process is Async @alexnik42

Comment: *the docs says it accepts props too*, the doc is referening to `setState` class method. `setTodos` is hook. both are different thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to change `submitTodoHandler` function in your `<Form>` component:

```
submitTodoHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.props.inputText) // outputs what you typed in the input
    this.props.setTodos(this.props.inputText);
  };
```

You define setState in functional component and pass it as a prop to class component. setState hook in functional components behaves slightly different from setState in class components, which you are referencing to.

In functional components setState (or setTodos in your case)  changes the state of the variable simply by using `setState(newVariableValue)` and accepts as a parameter previous state. As newVariableValue is passed with a prop (inputText) from `<App>` component to `<Form>` component, you can directly access it with `this.props.inputText`.

[Using the State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: ok got it , so useState in Function and in class are different versions so if my App Component was a class instead of a functional it would have worked properly right ? @alexnik42

Comment: @YuvrajAgarkar small modification of your code will be needed. I would also suggest to define setState logic in your App component (check this - [Passing setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50215364/can-we-pass-setstate-as-props-from-one-component-to-other-and-change-parent-stat)). Anyway, you do not need to specify props as a parameter in your setState function, as you have them in constructor by default when you create a class and can generally access them within your class.